# Does GKE Ingress with L7 ALB support gRPC-web to gRPC and gRPC to gRPC-web conversion?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, gcp-load-balancer

Does GKE Ingress in conjunction with L7 ALB offer any built-in functionality to convert incoming gRPC-web/REST requests to their corresponding gRPC format for forwarding to backend services, and vice versa (gRPC to gRPC-web/REST)?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately no.
however, you can use envoy proxy load-balance gRPC services on GKE. [documentation-url](https://%20load-balance%20gRPC%20services%20on%20GKE)